# Attachment's name is wrong decoded if norwegian letters are used

Tags: c#, encoding, sendmail, attachment

I have this piece of code which creates an attachment and sends email. If name of the file contains æ, ø or æ, the name is totally destroyed.

[image]

If I remove norwegian letters, everything is ok

[image]

```
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        doc.Save(stream, SaveFormat.Docx);

        mail.From = new MailAddress("no-replay@email.no");
        mail.To.Add("my@email.no");
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Subject = "Attachments test";
        mail.Body = "Hei,<br /><br />";
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var attachment = new Attachment(stream, "Name Å Æ Ø.docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        attachment.NameEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.server.com") {Port = 25};
        smtp.Send(mail);
```

How to get this work properly?

**SOLUTION**

I found a solution here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dotnetframeworkde/thread/b6c764f7-4697-4394-b45f-128a24306d55

Comment: Is `mail` a `MailMessage`? If so, could you check if all "encoding" properties, like `BodyEncoding`, `HeadersEncoding` and so on, have the same value?

Comment: All these parameters are UTF8 >  mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; mail.HeadersEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; It does not help.

Answer (score 2):

here is resolution from microsoft for .net framework 4

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2402064

Comment: direct download:                                                  64: http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%204.0%20-%20Windows%20XP,%20Windows%202003,%20Windows%20Vista,%20Windows%20Server%202008,%20Win7,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20(MSI)/nosp/DevDiv933059/30319.364/free/421618_intl_x64_zip.exe 

32: http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%204.0%20-%20Windows%20XP,%20Windows%202003,%20Windows%20Vista,%20Windows%20Server%202008,%20Win7,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20(MSI)/nosp/DevDiv933059/30319.364/free/421617_intl_i386_zip.exe

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `attachment.NameEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` to `attachment.NameEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`.

Comment: I have tried all Encodings. If I use Unicode name like this =utf-16MUAByg8........ is coming up.